# Why I can not add optional help parameter in console command?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 10 app I have a console command, in which only name parameter was required:

```
/**
 * Create a new CRUD Controller based on stubs/controllers.custom.stub file.
 *
 * @param {name} - Model name
 * @param {showDone?} - Optional. if set then done/undone methods are added
 * @param {transactionWithInterface?} - Optional. if set then transaction with interface class are used
 * If not set then standard DB methods are used
 */
class MakeCustomControllerCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {name} {showDone?} {transactionWithInterface?}';
```

I want to add optional parameter help and it appears that now all parameters are optional :

```
use App\Library\StubCodeContainer;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Str;

/**
 * Create a new CRUD Controller based on stubs/controllers.custom.stub file.
 *
 * @param {name?} - Optional. Model name
 * @param {showDone?} - Optional. if set then done/undone methods are added
 * @param {transactionWithInterface?} - Optional. if set then transaction with interface class are used
 * @param {help?} - Optional. if set then help text is shown, but not new controller is not created
 */
class MakeCustomControllerCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {name?} {showDone?} {transactionWithInterface?} {help?} ';
```

So command

```
php  artisan make:custom-controller  help
```

does not work as expected and with debugging :

```
$arguments = $this->arguments();
\Log::info(varDump($arguments, ' -1 $arguments::'));
```

I see :

```
 Array
(
    [command] => make:custom-controller
    [name] => help
    [showDone] =>
    [transactionWithInterface] =>
)
```

How better tio make it ?

Comment: shouldn t you just remove ? from {name?} if name is required??

Comment: Sorry, if I did not put clear my question. After I added Optional {help?} paramater, I had to make {name?}  optional too, as parameters "ModelName help" have no sence...

Comment: if i get the problem right, the optional help you added should show/explain the command, but, there is a built in --help parameter that should do just that allowing you to go back to the original ```protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {name} {showDone?} {transactionWithInterface?}';```, additionally you can add input descriptions (see docs) that explain the options in details as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several optional arguments they will be assigned values from the input string with priority from left to right.
So in your example:

```
protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {name?} {showDone?} {transactionWithInterface?} {help?} ';
```

You could give the argument `help` a value by first setting the three arguments before it.

```
php artisan make:custom-controller MyController yes yes help
```

This approach could be improved by using by [options](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan#options) for the optional arguments. Then the order of which you write them in doesn't matter, and you can set the last one without having to set the first ones. This is done by adding a `--` before the option in the signature. If you want to be able to pass values to the option you add a `=` after the option in the signature.

```
protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {--name=} {--showDone=} {--transactionWithInterface=} {--helpme=} ';
```

If you don't need to pass a value to the option, you just want it to be true or false you don't need to add the `=`.
It is also worth noting that the `--help` option is a default option in Laravel which I don't think that you can override. You can change most of what it prints by changing the `$description` and `$signature` variables.

I think that your final result should look like this:

```
protected $signature = 'make:custom-controller {name} {--showDone} {--transactionWithInterface} {--newArgument=}';
```

Since `showDone` and `transactionWithInterface` sound like they should be boolean. `--help` is not needed, but if you want to add a new option it could look like this.

```
php artisan make:custom-controller MyController --showDone --newArgument=help
```

And the values can be accessed like this:

```
var_dump($this->argument('name'));                   //string(12) "MyController"
var_dump($this->option('showDone'));                 //bool(true)
var_dump($this->option('transactionWithInterface')); //NULL
var_dump($this->option('newArgument'));              //string(4)"help"
```